# Program installer requires .NET framework 2.0 but I already have it

Tags: installation, .net-framework

I'm trying to install a program and getting message:

> This setup requires the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0.50727. Please install the
>   .NET Framework and run this setup
>   again. The .NET Framework can be
>   obtained from the web. Would you like
>   to do that?

Previously I've installed Visual Studio 2005 which comes with required version of .NET Framework.
In registry, I have SP set to 2 in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed .net framework 1.1 redistributable package and it worked.
Very strange.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder about the seriousness of MS developers. I feel trolled every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

Try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) while attempting to install. That tool should give you information which registry keys and which files are checked. My guess is that installation program checks for non-existant registry key. When Process Monitor tells you which read fails, just create that key and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least on service pack for .NET 2, ensure you have this installed (should be offered in Windows Update).

Comment: I've installed VS2005 SP1 and VS2005 for Windows 7 but I still can't get installer to work. I don't see any other .NET 2 related updates in the Windows Update.